# How do I crop an excel text cell to 250 character

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have text stored in microsoft excel 2010 text cells which I need to crop to 250 characters rounded up or down to the nearest full word.

So for example the text

> A lot of text ........ which ends like this

lets say the 250th character is the "i" in "like" I'd want the cell to convert to

> A lot of text ........ which ends like

I hope I've made my self clear.

Many Thanks

Nigel

Comment: What's your programming question?

Comment: Guess I'm in the wrong place lol but thanks for taking the time to comment.

Comment: This is programming because I am sure there is no easy way to do this with Worksheet functions.  So a custom worksheet function written in VBA is probably the choice.  But before I answer I need to think about it.

Comment: Ok, I am wrong.  There is an easy way to do this with builtin worksheet functions:  =IF(LEN(A1)>250,LEFT(A1,SEARCH(" ",A1,251)-1),A1)

Comment: Many Thanks, worked a treat :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the text is in column A, you can put this formula in column B and copy down:

```
=TRIM(LEFT(A1,250+FIND(" ",MID(A1,251,250)&" ")))
```

If you want to replace the contents of column A, after the formula do the following:

Copy column B -> Select cell A1 -> right-click -> paste special -> values -> OK

Then you can just delete column B.

*EDIT*: Adding alternate formulas:

```
=IF(LEN(A1)>250,LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1&" ",251)-1),A1)

=TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND(" ",A1&REPT(" ",251),251)))
```